# SVD calculation in R

Tags: r

How do I get actual matrix using Singular value decomposition(SVD)
 efficiently in R ,
cause `A=svd$u %*% svd$d %*% t(svd$v)` This is not an efficient way to get matrix A

Comment: [Package `svd`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svd/svd.pdf) perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Try `svd(A)$u%*%diag(svd(A)$d)%*%t(svd(A)$v)`.

```
set.seed(12345)
A <- matrix(data=runif(n=9, min=1, max=9), nrow=3)
A
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 6.767231 8.088997 3.600763
[2,] 8.006186 4.651848 5.073795
[3,] 7.087859 2.330974 6.821642

s <- svd(A)
D <- diag(s$d)
s$u %*% D %*% t(s$v)
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 6.767231 8.088997 3.600763
[2,] 8.006186 4.651848 5.073795
[3,] 7.087859 2.330974 6.821642
```

Answer (score 2):

Improving upon the answer by @MYaseen208

```
(s$u) %*% (t(s$v)*s$d)
```

This has one less matrix multiplication (which is an O(n^3) operation).

Comment: Another option would be to use the `Matrix` package, turn `s$d` into a `Diagonal` matrix, and take advantage of the matrix multiplication specialized for diagonal matrices.